# How to Add a YouTube Video to a Playlist via YouTube official PHP SDK

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-php-client

I am using the code in this page
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#upload_a_video
to upload a video to youtube. but i can't find away to put the uploaded video to an already exists playlist.

I found this class `Google_Service_YouTube_Resource_PlaylistItems` which has `insert` method but I have no clue how to use it

this is what I came up with

```
                $resourceId = new \Google_Service_YouTube_ResourceId();
                $resourceId->setVideoId( $status["id"] );
                $resourceId->setKind('youtube#video');



                $playlistItemSnippet = new \Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistItemSnippet();
                $playlistItemSnippet->setTitle('First video in the test playlist');
                $playlistItemSnippet->setPlaylistId($playlistId);
                $playlistItemSnippet->setResourceId($resourceId);


                $playlistItem = new \Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistItem();
                $playlistItem->setSnippet($playlistItemSnippet);
                $playlistItemResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->insert(
                    'snippet,contentDetails', $playlistItem, array());
```

this was the response

```
object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request)#698 (7) {
  ["method":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request":private]=>
  string(4) "POST"
  ["requestTarget":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request":private]=>
  NULL
  ["uri":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request":private]=>
  object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri)#749 (7) {
    ["scheme":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
    string(5) "https"
    ["userInfo":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["host":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
    string(18) "www.googleapis.com"
    ["port":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
    NULL
    ["path":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
    string(25) "/youtube/v3/playlistItems"
    ["query":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
    string(29) "part=snippet%2CcontentDetails"
    ["fragment":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["headers":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request":private]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Host"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(18) "www.googleapis.com"
    }
    ["content-type"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(16) "application/json"
    }
    ["X-Php-Expected-Class"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(35) "Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistItem"
    }
  }
  ["headerNames":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request":private]=>
 array(3) {
    ["content-type"]=>
    string(12) "content-type"
    ["host"]=>
    string(4) "Host"
    ["x-php-expected-class"]=>
    string(20) "X-Php-Expected-Class"
  }
  ["protocol":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request":private]=>
  string(3) "1.1"
  ["stream":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request":private]=>
  object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream)#730 (7) {
    ["stream":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    resource(589) of type (stream)
    ["size":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    NULL
    ["seekable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    bool(true)
    ["readable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    bool(true)
    ["writable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    bool(true)
    ["uri":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    string(10) "php://temp"
    ["customMetadata":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Note:
I can upload a video via the API so the authentication and connection and all the basic requirements is OK

Answer (score 0):

Here is a starting point from the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38685167/adding-video-to-playlist-with-youtube-api).

This is the code that solves the problem of the user.

```
$(function() {
    $('input.Chilltrap').on('click', function(e) {
        var chilltrap = this.id;     
        if( $("input[name=" + chilltrap + "]").prop('checked') ) {
            checkboxstatusCt = "Yes";
        }
        else {
            checkboxstatusCt = "No";
        }
        var url = "url.php";
        var params = "c="+checkboxstatusCt+"&s="+chilltrap;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {                         
                $("#error").html(xmlhttp.responseText);
                $("#error"). fadeIn('fast');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#error"). fadeOut('slow');
                },2000);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url+"?"+params,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    });
});
```

You can also check some related SO post listed below to get idea how they able to upload videos in playlist.

- [Youtube API (PHP) - how to add (existing) video to existing playlist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16692416/youtube-api-php-how-to-add-existing-video-to-existing-playlist)
- [Upload Video to Specific Playlist in youtube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35597780/upload-video-to-specific-playlist-in-youtube)
- [insert video into a playlist with youtube api v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650415/insert-video-into-a-playlist-with-youtube-api-v3)
- [Youtube PHP API - How do I add a specific video to a specific playlist using the PlaylistID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977680/youtube-php-api-how-do-i-add-a-specific-video-to-a-specific-playlist-using-the)

Comment: I already read the links before posting the question and they are not related to the problem I am having.
and I don't know what the code u posted even do!!

Comment: @DiaaSaada Did you solve your problem?
If yes, Please post the solution because i'm facing the same issue.

Comment: yes.I did,  by re-initialized `$client` and the `$service before setting the playlist